# Installing Python package via setup.py in existing environment

Tags: python, conda, setup.py, python-packaging

I am trying to install a python package.

I initially set up the environment for the package, which comes with the pre-req packages for its download.

```
~faleevamaria$ conda env create -f envrionment.yml
~faleevamaria$ conda activate ARTDeco
```

I then download the setup.py file provided in github, and try to run

`(ARTDECO) MA57747: ~faleevamaaria$ conda setup.py install`

However, it tells me that the package directory does not exist.

````
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing ARTDeco.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to ARTDeco.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to ARTDeco.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing requirements to ARTDeco.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to ARTDeco.egg-info/top_level.txt
error: package directory 'ARTDeco' does not exist```
````

My apologies if this a rather simple fix, I am new to python! Many thanks

Comment: It seems like there are quite a lot of details missing from this question. Did you download only the `setup.py`? -- I recommend your provide a full standalone [mre].